# Is this the same as long polling?

Tags: php, ajax, websocket, long-polling

I am creating a chat application and trying to use long polling to improve sending and receiving messages (while i go ahead to learn websocket). I heard of long polling and tried to see if its something like this.

```
var chatUpdate = function () {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "get_chat.php",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (response) {
          $(".msgView").html(response);
          if (response !== lastResponse) {
              var audio = new Audio('audio/solemn.mp3')
              audio.play()
              var msgView = $('.msgView');
              msgView.animate({scrollTop: msgView.prop("scrollHeight")}, 2000);
          }
          lastResponse = response
          setTimeout(chatUpdate, 15000);

      }
  });
};
setTimeout(chatUpdate, 2000);
```

I fill this is wrong cause all i am simply doing here is delaying when the `get_chat.php` is executed.

So please if i am wrong to long poll with this code. What is the best way for long polling.

And also does anyone have link to a very good php websocket tutorial (not framework).

Thanks very much.

Comment: No, it's not the same as long polling. You keep having to reopen the connection every time (for the `GET` to `get_chat.php`). That's not what long polling is. If you are using long polling you keep the connection open. But you can't do it with Javascript alone. Websockets is the way to go. Having said that the fact you're using `setTimeout` and are recursively calling the function, you've done more than some people might have, and it'll probably work.

Comment: @Andy thanks a bunch but do you have any links to a very good websocket tutorial. Thanks again.

Comment: You'd be better off at looking into a library that actually does it like http://socketo.me/. See http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world for a "hello world" example. If you want an overview of the concept (including why your code isn't really long polling) check out https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery. The last link isn't specific to websockets or anything, and was written some time ago, but it explains the concept quite well.